# AngularJS filtering using checkboxes are working like radio buttons

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to iterate through a list of books. I'm trying to use checkboxes to filter on the booktype (kindle, paperback, hardback). The checkboxes are filtering the data, but only one of the three can be checked at a time. If I try to check a second one, the first one unchecks. I'm not sure why and how to fix this. I have this ng-repeat:

```
<tr ng-repeat="det in details | orderBy:['-YEAR_READ','-UniqueCounter'] | filter:searchingFor ">
```

and my checkboxes look like this:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchingFor.BOOKTYPE" name="HardbackCheckBox" ng-true-value="'H'" ng-false-value="''">Hardback</label>&nbsp;
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchingFor.BOOKTYPE" name="KindleCheckBox" ng-true-value="'K'" ng-false-value="''">Kindle</label>&nbsp;
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchingFor.BOOKTYPE" name="PaperbackCheckBox" ng-true-value="'P'" ng-false-value="''">Paperback</label>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: can you upload the code in plunlr or fiddle

Comment: Change ng-model names. They are same!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I did to get this to work. I'm very new to AngularJS so it may not be the best solution, but it is working now.

1.) I changed the models on my checkbox, which was suggested:

```
<label>Hardback</label><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.H" ng-true-value="'H'"  ng-false-value=''  /><br/> 
<label>Kindle</label><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.K" ng-true-value="'K'"  ng-false-value=''  /><br/>
<label>Paperback</label><input  type="checkbox" ng-model="Filter.P" ng-true-value="'P'"  ng-false-value=''  />
```

2.)  I added a filter on the ng-repeat called chooseBookTypes:

```
<tr ng-repeat="det in details | orderBy:['-YEAR_READ','-UniqueCounter'] | filter:searchingFor | filter:chooseBookTypes">
```

3.)  Wrote a function in my controller that checks for the true value of each Filter model. BOOKTYPE is the field I'm examining in JSON.

```
$scope.chooseBookTypes = function(det){
return det.BOOKTYPE === $scope.Filter.P || det.BOOKTYPE === $scope.Filter.H ||  det.BOOKTYPE === $scope.Filter.K;
};
```

4.)  This would be optional, but by default I wanted each checkbox to be checked, so in my controller I set the value of each Filter model to the ng-true-value:

```
$scope.Filter = {
   H: 'H',
   K: 'K',
   P: 'P'
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

For all three checkboxes `ng-model="searchingFor.BOOKTYPE"` are same.I think that causes the issue

Answer (score 0):

ng-model behavior both three are same. ng-value can create sub scope. So this should work.

Change your code like this

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="searchingFor.BOOKTYPE" ng-value="{{det.value}}">
```

Comment: From the question: "The checkboxes are filtering the data, but **only one of the three can be checked at a time**."

Comment: oh, sorry for misunderstand.